# React with Redux, component unable to recognize a property passed from a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Kindly go over the code below, if its not clear enough, Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xrzqpo2lvp) for an extended version of my issue,

so I am passing some properties from a parent to a child comp., the parent is my `<Main />` comp., which is wrapped in a `<Provider>` comp. to allow it to access the store. Now, in the child, I have a function that renders info based on the passed props from the parent, here is my child comp. code

```js
//Home Component
...
const RenderCard = ({item, isLoading, errMess}) => {
  console.log(item.name)
  
  if(isLoading) {
    return(
      <Loading /> 
      )
  } 
  else if (errMess) {
    return (
      <h4>{errMess}</h4>
      )
  }
  else {
    return(
      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
    ) 
  }
}

const Home = props => {
  return (
   <RenderCard item={props.dish} isLoading={props.dishesLoading} errMess={props.dishesErrMess} />
 )
}
  
...
```

Here is how I pass the prop from the parent,

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    dishes: state.dishes,
    comments: state.comments,
    leaders: state.leaders,
    promotions: state.promotions
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(addComment(dishId, rating, author, comment)),
  fetchDishes: () => {
    dispatch(fetchDishes())
  }
})

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDishes()
    console.log(this.props.dishes.dishes.filter(dish => dish.featured)[0])
  }

  render() {
    const HomePage = () => { 
      <Home dish = {this.props.dishes.dishes.filter(dish => dish.featured)[0]} /> 
  }
}
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

the strange part is, in the first code snippet, line 4, the console.log(..) msg, successfully logs the desired info to the console, which means the props are passed and reached to the `<RenderCard />` comp. However, instead of rendering it on the window, I get a TypeError Cannot read property name of undefined.

please leave a comment below if any further parts of the code are needed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: About style: You don't need `return` statement after arrow if you only return something, it don't help reading. Use `prop-types` library and catch place where first you get wrong type of `item`. Use unit tests like jest - it's really easy to use it and you don't waste time on such questions.

Comment: If you don't want to use `prop-types` library use at least js docs for better IDE support.

Comment: thanks for your comment, But I am only using the return when conditionally rendering something based on the props passed from the parent. regarding the jest testing, well, I need to get this problem solved for now and then I will consider looking into unit testing

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, that you're not returning any component in your `Main` component's render method. You've declared a method `HomePage` instead.

Refer the code below. This should work.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the sandbox that works: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nopnq3jo0

You were trying to render before the dishes loaded. Hence, added a condition check if the dishes were loaded or not.

```
function Home(props) {
  return (
    !props.dishesLoading && (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row align-items-start">
          <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
            <RenderCard
              item={props.dish}
              isLoading={props.dishesLoading}
              errMess={props.dishesErrMess}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: could you please recheck the codesandbox, I initially forgot to add the <Redirect> to the <switch>, now its added since I am using the router to render the home if no routes are selected. thanks

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

PRoblem is that in your main component you are passing the dishesLoading prop to the Home component incorrectly. You need to access it from props with the name `isLoading` and not `dishesLoading`

```
const HomePage = () => {
      return (
        <Home
          dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter(dish => dish.featured)[0]}
          dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
          dishesErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
        />
      );
};
```

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr5zom6rjm)

Also in the `RenderCard` component you shouldn't access `item.name` before the data is loaded since initially its `undefined` in `console.log(item.name)`

Comment: thanks very much, its working now, thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Glad to have helped